# Why I can't directly set console.log() as callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, this, console.log

Why this code doesn't work

```
function callback(num, func) {
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        func();
    }
}

callback(4, console.log("Hello"));
```

I know I have to do like this:

```
callback(4, function() { console.log("hello"); });
```

But I still don't understand the reason why I have to do like that.

Comment: You're *calling* `console.log` in your snippet. The return value of that function call is used instead - as in the lower snippet - an anonymous function.

Comment: I bet you're using Google Chrome? Passing `console.log` does work in other browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets step through it to help you visualise what is going on.  When the interpreter reads your code, it evaluates function expressions inside-out.  That is to say:

```js
callback(4, console.log("Hello"));
//          ^------------------^---- is evaluated before "callback" is called.
```

A longer-form way of writing this which produces the same outcome would be:

```js
var result = console.log("Hello");
callback(4, result);
```

The `console.log` function doesn't have a defined return value (or at least not a standardised one) - though incidentally all functions in javascript return *something* - when unspecified this value is literally `undefined`.  So when you run your code you are essentially calling:

```js
callback(4, undefined);
```

This means that inside `callback`, trying to call `func` as a function will result in:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

This is why you need to encapsulate your logic in a new function-closure - whereby `func` obtains a reference to a callable `Function` object.

---

**So How Can I Tidy Up My Code?**

Generally in simple cases like this, what you have done to solve the problem is perfectly acceptable but with more complex logic, you can often end up with several levels of nested callbacks (sometimes referred to as *"callback-soup"*).  To improve readability where code reuse is common you can introduce a function-factory which hides away the nastiness, for example:

```js
function myLogger(message){
    return function(){
        console.log(message);
    }      
}

callback(4, myLogger('hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you mentioned console.log(), you asked the js engine to evaluate it and it does and passes the result as the 2nd arg to the callback function and not a function object as it expects and hence the call doesn't behave as u desire.
The working case correctly passes a function object when u pass a function(){} construct.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the console.log('foo') as a callback you will call the log return as a function.

A solution is to put your console.log in a function:

```
function callback(num, func) {
   for(var i = 0; i < num; i++)
      func();
}
callback(4, function(){
   console.log("Hello2")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because functions are first-class citiziens in Javascript (meaning functions can be stored in variables). passing a function as an argument will return a reference to the function definition rather than the function call you're trying to invoke.
It does however evaluate your console.log beforehand and passes it on as a variable and since your log's function call doesn't return anything it passes undefined to your callback function.

```
function test( logFunction ){
    logFunction( 'test' )
}

test( alert )
```

Is an example of this behaviour. It's also the reason closures like the one demonstrated by Remy J work.

```
function callback(num, func) {
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        func( "Hello" );
    }
}

callback(4, alert);
```

This would work.