# Why I can't pass console.log as a callback argument in Chrome (and Safari)?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, firefox, jquery-deferred

The following snippet will produce an error in Chrome (and Safari) while it works in Firefox.

I'd expect to have 2 numbers shown in javascript console, but in Chrome I only get the first and then an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

```js
// a generic promise that return a random float
var makePromise = function() {
  return $.Deferred().resolve(Math.random());
}

// This works in all browsers
makePromise().then(function(d) {
  console.log(d);
});
// This works in firefox only
makePromise().then(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why is this happening?

Side note: my question is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29317045/518204).

### Update

Thanks to comments and answer to use `console.log` as callback one need to do

```
makePromise().then(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: Probably some webkit security limitations.

Comment: `console.log.bind(console)`. Nothing guarantees it's a "static" function.

Comment: Related/dupe: [log = console.log, throws illegal invocation error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31881897/1529630)

Comment: As @zerkms says, `console.log.bind(console)`. The amazing thing is that `console.log` should work in FF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a chromebook I can duplicate the problem as follows:

```
function do4(cb){ cb(1); cb(2); cb(3); cb(4); }

do4(console.log)
VM1491:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at do4 (<anonymous>:2:19)
    at <anonymous>:2:12
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)do4 @ VM1491:2(anonymous function) @ VM1552:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM1288:905InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM1288:838InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM1288:694
```

But this works fine, and indeed points toward the problem:

```
do4(console.log.bind(console))
VM1491:2 1
VM1491:2 2
VM1491:2 3
VM1491:2 4
```

Why is that?

In chrome, `console` by itself returns an `Object` of prototype `Console`,
 look:

```
console
Console {} memory: MemoryInfo__proto__: Console
```

It may seem odd thinking of `console` as an `Object`, but it is.  `console` has several other lesser-used methods that are not used as often as `console.log` but are documented in [MDN Console Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) and [Chrome Console Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api)

And here we get to a big Javascript-ism that can confuse people:

Javascript methods are *unbound methods*.  That is, the methods are not bound to any particular object.

So `console.log` is a function, but it is the function only and does not preserve its binding of `this` to `console`.

The variable binding is referred to inside a function's code by a magic `this` variable, which can be set with [`function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [`function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

When `console.log()` is called, JS does the binding of the function code's `this` to the `console` object.  But when  `console.log` is merely passed as a function, it does not do the binding, so that other code can use it more flexibly.  This behavior is inconvenient with console.log and many other methods, but in some cases adds needed flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`deferred.resolveWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/)

```js
// a generic promise that return a random float
var makePromise = function() {
  // set `this` to `window.console` , 
  // pass arguments within array
  return $.Deferred().resolveWith(window.console, [Math.random()]);
}

// This works in all browsers
makePromise().then(console.log)
//.then(function(d) {
//  console.log(d);
//});
// This works in firefox only
makePromise().then(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: `makePromise` was just a minimal reproducible example. I don't want to change all my code that return promises only to debug it.